# PHP XML Read Multi Nodes

Tags: php, xml

i have a xml like below. How can parse this? i don't know how i can do this? 
OZELLIK and DEGER is diffrent sometimes 5 sometimes 10. Please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <STOKLAR>
        <STOK>
            <SKU>1234</SKU>
            <OZELLIKLER>
                <OZELLIK>Ekran Kartı Belleği </OZELLIK>
                <DEGER>Paylaşımlı </DEGER>
            </OZELLIKLER>
        </STOK>
        <STOK>
            <SKU>1454</SKU>
            <OZELLIKLER>
                <OZELLIK>İşlemci Üreticisi </OZELLIK>
                <DEGER>Intel </DEGER>
                <OZELLIK>İşlemci Tipi </OZELLIK>
                <DEGER>Intel Core i5 </DEGER>
            </OZELLIKLER>
        </STOK>
    </STOKLAR>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Are ozellik and deger pairs?

Comment: Yes one ozellik one deger pair

Comment: It is strange that they aren't wrapped in another tag then. If you can modify the structure of the XML, I'd suggest that. By the way, what is the output you're aiming for?

Comment: its coming from company thats why i cant modify

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: SKU
-Ozellik
-Deger
SKU
-Ozellik
-Deger

Answer (score 1):

It isn't that difficult with DOM and Xpath expressions:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// iterate STOK element nodes
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/ROOT/STOKLAR/STOK') as $stok) {
    // fetch first SKU child element node as string
    var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(SKU)', $stok));
    // iterate OZELLIK element nodes in OZELLIKLER
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('OZELLIKLER/OZELLIK', $stok) as $ozellik) {
        var_dump(
            // content of current OZELLIK
            $ozellik->textContent, 
            // first following sibling element node, if DEGER, as string
            $xpath->evaluate('string((./following-sibling::*)[1][self::DEGER])', $ozellik)
        );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
string(4) "1234"
string(22) "Ekran Kartı Belleği "
string(14) "Paylaşımlı "
string(4) "1454"
string(21) "İşlemci Üreticisi "
string(6) "Intel "
string(15) "İşlemci Tipi "
string(14) "Intel Core i5 "
```

`DOMXpath::evaluate()` can return a node list or a scalar value depending on the expression. The second argument sets the context node for the expression. Here is an explanation of the last (most complex) expression:

- Get the following sibling element nodes
  `following-sibling::*`
- Limit to the first found node
  `(following-sibling::*)[1]`
- Filter by node name DEGER
  `(following-sibling::*)[1][self::DEGER]`
- Return text content of this node, empty string if no node was found
  `string((following-sibling::*)[1][self::DEGER])`

By default expressions work on the "child" axis. The expression uses two other axes "following-sibling" and "self" to look for the required nodes.